# Bootstrap dropdown on navbar can't dropdown when active .NET Core

Tags: html, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have tried searching for an answer but came nowhere close to finding one. Basically I have a navbar and if I select an item, the the dropdown becomes active and as such I can't click the dropdown again and select another one. Let's say I click YYY, and I want to switch to ZZZ, that would not be possible until I leave for another page, the dropdown become inactive and click ZZZ. Is there any solution for this? Thank you very much.

```html
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a asp-area="" asp-controller="FOO" asp-action="FOO" class="nav-link">FOO</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a asp-area="" asp-controller="FOO" asp-action="FOO" class="nav-link">FOO</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a asp-area="FOO" asp-controller="" asp-action="FOO" class="nav-link">FOO</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a asp-area="" asp-controller="FOO" asp-action="FOO" class="nav-link">FOO</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Title
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="XXX" asp-action="YYY" class="dropdown-item">YYY</a>
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="XXX" asp-action="ZZZ" class="dropdown-item">ZZZ</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

It essentially refuses to dropdown when I'm inside one of the pages. Meaning if I'm inside

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="XXX" asp-action="YYY" class="dropdown-item">YYY</a>
```

the dropdown will not work at all and I can't click to ZZZ.

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: Give me awhile. But this is the full codes for the dropdown already. Is it necessary to show the other buttons?

Comment: If you need help, it would be better to post all the code necessary so we can reproduce your problem, try the snippet feature, or post a codepen, jsfiddle or something similar ;)

Comment: This is a razor view so the "full" codes won't be so "full" and it won't run on codepen either as it won't show the change page issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the issue is caused by turbolinks which doesn't exactly reload some parts of the page, resulting in this weird behaviour